# What should be the 5-letter word?

Tags: word, wordplay

[image]

Find out the five letter words using the letters given at the bottom which simultaneously expresses the inner meaning of the above four pictures.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Source** $:$ https://m.facebook.com/instantgames/play/498625833822107/?source=fblite_bookmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from

> The game 4 Pics 1 Word, I think;

The answer is

> STINK